# Why don’t the buds in my Shasta Daisy open?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers

Planted this Shasta daisy from a pot after full flowering last year. We had a very snowy winter, but it came back (cut down near the ground in fall)and seems so healthy. It has many buds, but they haven’t opened in 3-4 weeks. It gets lots of Sun and I keep the soil moist. What could be the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your plant looks very healthy.

[Shasta daisy bloom time ranges from early summer to **early fall**](https://www.provenwinners.com/learn/how-plant/shasta-daisy) . These improved daisies are more robust, with larger flowers and a longer bloom time than their wild counterparts.

- If you're in USDA Zone 6 or 7, the plant's clock has not triggered it to pop open yet, *buds notwithstanding*.
- Feed a bloom buster if you like (10-50-10 or at least 10-15-10), but it'll open in July or August when it's ready.

Comment: Yes, I’m in Zone 7 so sounds like I just need to be patient. Thank you so much!